# mid((user)from(-1)) meaning in mysql. what does from(-1) mean?

Tags: mysql, database

what does the following query mean in mysql?

```
select  user  from mysql.user where user=''!=(mid((user)from(-1))='t')
```

do you know what's the meaning of `mid((user)from(-1)`? it's very strange for me. user is the name of one of the tables in mysql

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there anything not covered in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid), the MySQL `MID()` function is a synonym for the `SUBSTRING()` function. The `SUBSTRING()` function can be called in different ways (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)), among them in the form

```
SUBSTRING(str FROM pos)
```

This means "*extract the substring from the string `str`, starting at the position `pos`*".

The documentation also states:

> It is also possible to use a negative value for `pos`. In this case, the beginning of the substring is `pos` characters from the end of the string, rather than the beginning.

So that means, `mid((user)from(-1)` should give you the last character of the contents of `user`.